# When two random variables that have the same law... Can they be happily exchanges?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Imagine, $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables which have the same law, which we denote by $X\sim Y$. We have then a third random variable $Z$. Can we say that
$$(X,Z)\sim (Y,Z)?$$

In what cases is this true?

Thanks!

Comment: Please share your thoughts on the question so far :)

Comment: Try $X=0$ or $1$ each with probability $\frac12$ and $Y=Z=1-X$

Comment: I really do not have any intuition about it :( I don't see why the example above helps. Aren't all of them equally distributed? and hence $(X,Z)\sim (Y,Z)$?

Comment: mark, no $(X,1-X)\not\sim(X,X)$ in the example @Henry gave.

Comment: In my example $(X,Z)$ is supported on $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ while $(Y,Z)$ is supported on $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$

Comment: I see, thanks a lot and what a pity haha :)

Answer (score 1):

If $Z$ is independent of $X$ and independent of $Y$, then $(X,Z )\sim (Y,Z)$. Indeed, if $s,t\in\mathbf R$, then 
 \begin{align}  
\mathbb P(X\leqslant s,Z\leqslant t)&=\mathbb P(X\leqslant s)\mathbb P(Z\leqslant t)\quad\mbox{ since $X$ and $Y$ are independent}\\
&= \mathbb P(Y\leqslant s)\mathbb P(Z\leqslant t)\quad \mbox{ because }X\sim Y  \\
&=\mathbb P(Y\leqslant s,Z\leqslant t)\quad\mbox{ since $Y$ and $Y$ are independent}.
\end{align}
In general, it is not true that $(X,Z)\sim (Y,Z)$; for example, if $Z=Y$ and $f(u,v)=u-v$, then we should have $f(X,Z)\sim f(Y,Z)$, hence $Y-X\sim 0$, which would mean that $X=Y$ almost surely.

Answer (score 1):

A counter-example that I enjoy is the following. Let $X=Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $Y=-X$. Then $$X\stackrel{d}{=}Y,$$ but $(X,Z)=(X,X)$ is concentrated in the identity while $(Y,Z)=(-X,X)$ is concentrated on the minus identity.